# i have two table in access I want to recall my information by code(similar index match in excel)

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

[image]

when i write it20 in tables (ind) call my infomation from sam
please help me

Comment: What is in your sam table?

Comment: @CHill60 This is an example. My main table contained thousands of values

Comment: I can't tell you how to join tables if I don't know what columns are in them. I don't want to see all the data!. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Surely you'd want a form and not a table?  Why duplicate data by pulling it from Sam into Ind?  Create a form, add your Code value and use a query to return the values from Sam.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook can you give me a exampel file